# When a button or checkbox is clicked, what css code do we use to select the container div?

Tags: css

When I click the navigation button, I want to select the navigation div. What css code should I write for this?

```
<div class="navigation">   
   <input type="checkbox" id="navi-toggle" class="navigation__checkbox" 
    name="checkbox">

   <label for="navi-toggle" class="navigation__button">
        <span class="navigation__icon"></span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: need more details

Comment: Create a js fiddle

Comment: Be really careful that you indent your code properly, especially with HTML since it tends to disappear if it isn't.

Comment: That said, it still isn't entirely clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "select"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I assume you're asking is how do I target a parent container with CSS when a child container is clicked. If so its not possible, but the same selector is valid for the parent. For instance if you have an a tag inside of a div and you click on the a, you've also clicked on the div tag.

**Edit I say the same selector is valid. In some cases this is not true if the child was removed from the standard flow of the document through floats or absolute positioning and probably a few other fringe cases.

Here's some pseudo code:

CSS

```
div.parent:active{
  background:red;
}
a.child:hover{
  color:blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<a class="child">Link</a>
</div>
```